# if-else comprehension with dictionary not working in python3

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x, list-comprehension, if-statement

```
dlist=['All my loving','All my bros','And all sis']
```

I would like to create a dictionary such that all words (as keys) are assigned a value which is index of dlist in which the words appear.
For example,
'All':{0,1}, 'my':{0,1},'sis'={2} etc.

Somehow this does not work:

```
dict={}
{w:{num} if w not in dict.keys() else dict[w].add(num) for (num,strn) in enumerate(dlist) for w in strn.split()}
```

This returns

```
{'All':{2}, 'my':{2}}
```

Looks like else statement is being ignored. Any pointers?
Thanks

Comment: Once you have two `for` loops and one `if` statement in a single dict comprehension, consider breaking it up into a few more lines.

Comment: You're throwing away the results of your dict comprehension by not assigning a name to it, *and* you're mutating your existing dict as part of the comprehension. On top of that, you have *named* the variable `dict`, which is in itself confusing. Almost as if you've *tried* to write it in the most obtuse way possible. Use better variable names and don't try to write it all in one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work because you are trying to access dict.keys while you are creating dict in a dict comprehension. If this was in a for loop, dict.keys would be updated each element, but the dict comprehensions ensures that the dict is not updated mid-creation to improve speed.

Something like this should work:

```
myDict = {}
for (num, strn) in enumerate(dlist):
    for w in strn.split():
        if w not in myDict:
            myDict[w] = {num}
        else:
            myDict[w].add(num)
```

Comment: Thanks RiaD and Jmac. I have a code like that given by Jmac but was trying to see if dict comprehension could be somehow used. I did not understand why it wasn't working by rewriting the above code in one line comprehension. Thanks to Jmac, it is clear to me now - trying to get the chicken out before it is hatched!

Comment: Rename `dict`. It shadows the builtin `dict`.